# Compile and load object file from different makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm new with makefiles and trying to write one like this:

```
folder_1
   |---- makefile_1
   |---- output_1

folder_2
   |---- makefile_2
   |---- output_2
```

`makefile_1` compiles some code and generates `.o` inside `output_1` folder.

my goal is to call `makefile_1` from within `makefile_2` and generate `.exe` file in `folder_2`

This is example of `makefile_2`:

```
target: obj_1.o obj_2.o
    $(CC) -I$(INCLUDE) obj_1.o obj_2.o -o target

obj_2.o: ...files...
    $(CC) -I$(INCLUDE) -c ...files... 

obj_1.o: //<--- how to make and call obj_1 from folder_1?
```

So the question is:

1. How can I call `makefile_1` from `makefile_2`?
2. How to use the `.o` that was generated by `makefile_1` to create `.exe` in `folder_2`?

Thanks.

Comment: you can achieve this by using my library for `GNU make` https://github.com/igagis/prorab take a look at wiki and read about basic concepts, it explains how to include one makefile into another and add build dependencies

Comment: basically, your `folder1` should make a static library `.a` and `floder2` should use that static library to build executable

Comment: Where do you want `obj_1.o` to reside? In `folder_1/output_1/`, or someplace else?

Comment: probably via `make -C ..\folder1`...but there will be some issues: this will not check for changes to any dependencies of obj_1.o's sources if obj_1.o exists.  You can define the obj_1.o target to be ".PHONY", but that will launch folder1's makefile _every time_.  These are just some of the reasons people don't really like to use sub-makefiles.